# How to integrate live magento site to localhost without effecting live site

Tags: magento-1.9

I downloaded live site to my local machine. And I also changed `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` with my local url.

After these all configurations site is not working in my local machine.

It is showing error as in below screenshot

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c03t1je6b

Do you have any Idea what is missing..

Comment: goto your magento dir/errors/ make local.xml.sample as local.xml for checking the issue and afte that refresh page chech what is the issue .It show the error

Comment: Also, clear var/cache and var/sessions

Comment: I have already cleared var/cache and var/sessions

Comment: have you seen the error message?what is the issue?

Comment: And dir/erroes/ there was already file local.xml where I  deleted this file. It shown me error like in this screenshot..

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a73t1lk45

Comment: And you opened the report file mentioned in the error report? It is in var/[somewhere] and it is what you need to check next.

Answer (score 2):

When setting up the live site to my local computer what I follow is:

1. Download the code base.
2. Download the database.
3. Import the database to the mysql
4. Put the code to the server webroot from where I can execute it using browser for e.g I am using wampserver on windows 7 so I put code into the `C:\wamp\www\local` dir.
5. First remove all the folders and files from the `webroot/var/cache/` directory
6. Backup your `local.xml` file and delete the `local.xml` file from `webroot/app/etc/` directory
7. Then from the browser access the url for the local site, for e.g mine would be `http://localhost/local/`, Magento will
   automatically start the installation process, where you need to
   provide new login details for admin and your local site URL etc, for your local environment.
8. It will not take
   much time and your local site will work as your live site.

Comment: already did that but not solved brother